# Can you change the realm configuration of @ObservedResults to get new results on the fly?

Tags: swiftui, realm

***Context***

I have two different realms that a user can switch between at any point they decide; in-memory or on-disk.

I store this Realm configuration on an observable object which publishes the change when required:

```
class RealmServiceConfig: ObservableObject {
    static var config = CurrentValueSubject<Realm.Configuration?, Never>(nil)
}
```

I have a class that stores realm filters/sorts as `@Published` variables that a user can change at any point.

```
class Store: ObservableObject
{
    static var shared = Store()
    
    @Published var realmFilter: NSPredicate? = nil
    
    @Published var realmSortKeyPath: String = "fieldOnMyRealmModel"
    @Published var realmSortKeyPathAscending: Bool = false
}
```

I have two views:

*ListView* - This shows the live results of Objects in the current Realm.

As the filter/sort changes, the `filteredObjects` is recalculated thanks to the `@Published` values, but, it still points to the same config.

```
//import SwiftUI
//import Combine
//import RealmSwift

struct ListView: View
{
    @ObservedObject var store = Store.shared
    
    @ObservedResults(MyRealmModel.self, configuration: RealmServiceConfig.config.value) var unfilteredObjects
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let filteredObjects = unfilteredObjects
            .filter(store.realmFilter ?? NSPredicate(value: true))
            .sorted(by: [SortDescriptor(keyPath: "\(store.realmSortKeyPath)", ascending: store.realmSortKeyPathAscending)])
        
        return VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(filteredObjects) { object in
                        Text(object.name)
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*SettingsView* - The user can change their Realm configuration between in-memory and on-disk here which updates the aforementioned `RealmServiceConfig.config` value

When navigating to *SettingsView*, the *ListView* is moved to the background, it is not removed from the view hierarchy.

***Question***

When a user changes the realm and therefore updates the `RealmServiceConfig.config` value, is it possible to force reload `@ObservedResults` with the latest configuration?

Based on the current setup, even though my configuration parameter points to the published value, this is never applied.

***Workaround***

I have implemented this on a model class that stores the `Results<Object>` in a `@Published` variable which allows me to react and update the query based on the config changes and pass the results through to the views.

It would just be cleaner to have this all contained in the SwiftUI view where it's needed.

Maybe this is not available yet/works against how `@ObservedResults` is meant to be used?

Comment: What's the plan for this `@ObservedResults(Object.self`? The observed results are typically a Realm Model. And no, you won't be able to change the config on the fly without re-observing the results.

Comment: @Jay the `unfilteredObjects` is then filtered/sorted by dynamic filters/sorts available to the user which can be changed at any point. The new filtered/sorted results are then passed down to child views to be displayed and re-loaded as required.

Comment: Hmm. I cannot get that line to even compile. It throws an error *Referencing initializer 'init(_:configuration:filter:keyPaths:sortDescriptor:)' on 'ObservedResults' requires that 'Object' (aka 'RealmSwiftObject') conform to 'Identifiable'* - whereas this `@ObservedResults(MyModel.self) var myModel` works correctly and compiles.

Comment: @Jay to note, `Object` is just a general placeholder for any Realm model. Apologies if that wasn't clear. I have updated the question content to reflect this.

Comment: I would think, since @ObservedResults is a property wrapper that points to a type of Realm Object at a particular location (determined by the config when the code executes), if the config is changed, then it would still be referencing the objects specified in the original config. e.g. changing the config doesn't generate a 'reload' event. Same thing for say, filtering; `let results = realm.objects(MyObject.self).filter(some_filter)` changing some_filter would require re-running that code to adhere realm to the updated filter. Just thinking out loud on this and could be wrong.

Comment: @Jay I have added another update to the question to provide more code and context for what I would like to achieve.

Comment: I've reviewed the property wrapper code for `@ObservedResults` and it really looks like if the filter, sort or configuration is changed on the object, it *appears* like the object reloads the results with fresh data. They all have `didSet` calls which then forces a refresh `let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration`. So now I am thinking it would work.