# In SwiftUI, sorted(by: ) operation triggered from a sheet view, need to show a ProgressView while operation completes

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, realm

From Results View:

```
struct ResultsView: View {
@State private var selectedSort : Int = 1

func selectedSorter(selectedSort: Int, results: [Product]) -> [Product] 
    switch selectedSort {
        case 1:
            return results
        case 2:
            return results.sorted(by: { (first, second) -> Bool in
                        return second.price < first.price
                })
        Ect....
        default:
            print("Off")
            return results
        
        }
}

var body: some View {
        
        let results = selectedSorter(selectedSort: selectedSort, results: results)
```

This operation takes time. I am calling it from a .sheet view called FilterView:

```
struct FiltersView: View {
var progressHide : Bool = true
@Binding var selectedSort:Int

ProgressView("Sorting...please wait").isHidden(progressHide)

Picker("Sort by", selection: $selectedSort) {
                    Text("Off").tag(1)
                    Text("Price High to Low").tag(2)
                    Ect...
                }.pickerStyle(.wheel)

}
```

So my question is, how can I toggle progressHide in the FilterView from Results View to show the ProgressView while the seletedSorter operation happens?

In my case, I am sorting over 5000 results with images involved, it sometimes can take up to 30 seconds of a frozen screen, kinda hurting the UX cause the screen is frozen.

Comment: I have tried a closure on the selectedSorter func, to show ProgressView on start and hide on end, but it doesn't work. Or I am not writing it correctly. I also tried putting a .sheet view over the FilterView, but same issue, cannot hide it after operation finishes.

Comment: have you tried using a `@Binding var progressHide: Bool`, same as you do with `selectedSort`?

Comment: You probably going to want to avoid sorting that way. Realm results are lazily loaded - meaning that thousands of objects have a very small footprint. As soon as you work with them using Swift high level functions (like .map, .sorted) ALL the objects are loaded into memory, slowing down and potentially causing random crashes if there are lots of objects. Additionally returning them like this `results: [Product]` stuffs them all into an array - best to avoid that. For sorting see [Sorting](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/examples/read-and-write-data/#sort-query-results).

Comment: Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71939747/can-you-change-the-realm-configuration-of-observedresults-to-get-new-results-on) as it has some code you may find useful.